# getting NoClassDefFoundError using selenium web driver

Tags: java, apache-poi, openxml, junit4

I am getting the following error while trying to open an excel file using selenium JUni4 web driver in eclipse. Error and code is shown below. I am new to JAVA. Please help.

```
public void xlRead_TC(String sPath, int sSheet) throws Exception{   
    //Workbook book = Workbook.createWorkbook(f);       
    System.out.println("Step 1B  - Opening excel files Reached");
    File myxl = new File(sPath);
    FileInputStream myStream = new FileInputStream(myxl);
    //Workbook w;
    //w = Workbook.getWorkbook(myStream);

    XSSFWorkbook myWB = new XSSFWorkbook(myStream);
    //XSSFSheet mySheet = myWB.getSheetAt(sSheet);  // Referring to 1st  sheet

    //xRows_Inp = mySheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
    //xCols_Inp = mySheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    System.out.println("Rows are " + xRows_Inp);
    System.out.println("Cols are " + xCols_Inp);


    //Workbook[] wbs = new Workbook[] { new HSSFWorkbook(), new XSSFWorkbook() };

    //xRows_TC = mySheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
    //xCols_TC = mySheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    //System.out.println("Rows are " + xRows_TC);
    //System.out.println("Cols are " + xCols_TC);
    //xData_TC = new String[xRows_TC][xCols_TC];
}
```

Exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:154)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:141)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:54)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you run an older version of POI which still required the dom4j third party library. You have two options:

1) Upgrade to the latest release of POI where this library is not needed any more

2) Add the dom4j jar file to your classpath. The jar-file is part of the binary distribution of POI.

Answer (score 0):

I got issue like you somtimes. You can do by this way: rebuild project + refresh project in IDE.
If it still does not work, you should restart IDE. Hope this help :))